# type to begin effect (HTML, CSS, JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website which I am currently building and would like to implement a 'type to begin affect'.

I have the following JQuery:

```
$('body').keypress(function()
{
console.log('hi');
});
```

Which is working in the way I am alerted to the fact a key has been pressed, however I need to capture the key(s) pressed for insertion into a popup modal I will be showing on type. Ideally I wanted to select a specific input meaning I could just use val() however when autoselecting the input I wanted the 'flashing text cursor' does not appear instead it highlights the element the standard select blue. If it could be achieved that I could select a specified element by default and have it look exactly the way it would have had I clicked it that would be brilliant.

Comment: It is just the same when you bind a keypress to a input. You need to add the parameter received: `$('body').keypress(function(e)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the keycode, then simulate a keypress event on a specified input:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
    var keyEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    keyEvent.which = e.which; // capture keycode value
    $("input").trigger(keyEvent); //Change to whatever input you want to append to
});
```